# Auto-Scroll in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html

My application is a Live chat. I have a Div to wrap the messages, each message is a div, so, after a few messages my DOM looks like this :

```
<div id = "divChatHistory">
   <div id = "msg1> Message number one </div>
   <div id = "msg2> Message number two </div>
   <div id = "msg3> Message number three </div>
   // ...
</div>
```

Now a need to auto-scrool the divChatHistory for each message, and its realy simple:

```
function AutoScroll() {
    $('#<%= divChatHistory.ClientID%>').scrollTop(100000000000);
}
```

but it works only in Internet Explorer (IE) in FireFox (FF) not happens.

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

```
 function AutoScroll() {
    if (chkRolagem[0].checked) {
        if (jQuery.browser.msie)
            divChatHistory.scrollTop(100000000000);
        else
            divChatHistory.scrollTop(-100000000000);
    }
}
```

If IE, positive number.

If FF, negative number

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[scrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)** plugin. See a **[demo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)**

Check this one also

**[Animated Scrolling with jQuery 1.2](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/09/animated-scrolling-with-jquery-12)**

Comment: i will take a look at the plugin.