# Scroll Firefox using Watir Webdriver

Tags: ruby, firefox, watir, watir-webdriver

I'd like to scrape a website that dynamically generates more content as I scroll down the web browser. I have seen a related post, [Auto-Scroll in FireFox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251991/auto-scroll-in-firefox), but it doesn't answer my question.

Is it possible to scroll a webpage until the end of page (no more content is generated by the web server) or until a few refreshes using Watir web-driver?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have recently tried to do something like that, and to my surprise looks like webdriver does not have support for scrolling. I did find two workarounds.

This will send `space` to the browser, and it will scroll down (works on twitter.com, for example):

```
browser.send_keys :space
```

This will scroll to the element, and if the element is at the bottom of the page, it will load more content:

```
browser.element.wd.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Zeljko!! It's exactly what I wanted!!